# How to remap keycodes (not symbols)?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

Using XKB I can change the symbol for the TAB key:

```
key  <TAB> {
    type= "ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Overlay1_Enable ]
};
```

However, Google Chrome detects keycode `23` (aka `<TAB>`) irrespective of the symbol and tabs to the next element.

I need some way to generate an innocuous keycode (any will do) when the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is pressed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution.

I make an overlay

```
key  <TAB> {
    overlay2=<HYPR>
};
```

Then set the rarely-used pause/break key to trigger the overlay:

```
key <PAUS> {
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Overlay2_Enable,           Overlay2_Enable ]
};

interpret Overlay2_Enable+AnyOfOrNone(all) {
    action= LockControls(controls=Overlay2);
};
```

Now, after pressing the pause/break key, the overlay sticks and TAB (keycode) is forever remapped to HYPER (keycode!). Ideally I would like a solution that does not require pressing a key in order to initialize.